# How do we PUSH new updates on iCal events?

Tags: events, push, icalendar

> How can we **PUSH** to the subscribed device new updates?

I can easily generate a `.ics` file from my CRM Diary, and successfully importing to Google as a new Calendar URL, but when I create a new entry in my CRM Diary, **how can I alert** "Google Calendar" **for the new created/updated event?**

I'm a little lost, and I can't find a solution, I read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) over and over but ... I'm missing something :(

Any help is **greatly appreciated**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this .NET iCal Library

> [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/Default.aspx)

And all I need to do was check the incoming requests like [`dougday`](https://sourceforge.net/users/dougday/) answered me on [my question on their forum](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/forums/forum/656447/topic/3852295)